# Crop Texture2D Spritesheet

Tags: xna, sprite-sheet

I'm developing a game which will have spritesheets, like so:

[image: E.G of spritesheet]

I know when you do `spriteBatch.Draw(...)` you can draw a certain portion of the image, but for what I'm doing, I need to have a separate `Texture2D` object per frame.

I've done google searches, but all I can find is outdated code :/

**UPDATE** The code posted by MJP [here](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/517683-xna-rendering-stuff-to-a-texture2d-then-rendering-that-texture2d-to-the-screen/) is very nearly what I need... however, there isn't a `RenderTarget2D.GetTexture()` function in XNA 4.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wow ok... A whole lot more google searching revealed:

```
Texture2D tex = (Texture2D)renderTarget;
```

Just a simple cast :)

Here's my final code:

```
    public static Texture2D Crop(Texture2D image, Rectangle source)
    {
        var graphics = image.GraphicsDevice;
        var ret = new RenderTarget2D(graphics, source.Width, source.Height);
        var sb = new SpriteBatch(graphics);

        graphics.SetRenderTarget(ret); // draw to image
        graphics.Clear(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));

        sb.Begin();
        sb.Draw(image, Vector2.Zero, source, Color.White);
        sb.End();

        graphics.SetRenderTarget(null); // set back to main window

        return (Texture2D)ret;
    }
```